# DC.js DataTable not showing as it should

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have the following code:

```
'use strict'

var ccgTable  = dc.dataTable('.data-table');

d3.csv('../data/rdata.csv', function (data) {
  var xdata = crossfilter(data);
  var all   = xdata.groupAll();

  var ccgDimension = xdata.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.ccgcode;
  });

  var ccgDimensionGrp = ccgDimension.group();

    // fact table
    ccgTable
      .dimension(ccgDimension)
      .group(function(d) {
        return d.metric;
      })
      .columns([
        {
          label: 'CCG Code',
          format: function (d) {
              return d.ccgcode;
          }
        },
        {
          label: 'Metric',
          format: function (d) {
              return d.metric;
          }
        }]);
  dc.renderAll();
});
```

I should be seeing a table with two columns, one titled `CCG Code` and the other `Metric`, but instead I am seeing [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5r1bk04z/).

The Chrome console is showing me an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to use 2.0 features with dc.js 1.7.5.

In the future, it will be easier for others to help with your JSFiddles if you use the "External Resources" feature rather than pasting all the javascript into your sources.

I forked your fiddle and used this feature. In this version, it fails like yours does:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.5/dc.js
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/eLbeaxe9/2/

But in this version (which is the first I tried, with dc.js 2.0 beta 29) it seems to work, although the formatting needs some help:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.0.0-beta.29/dc.js
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/eLbeaxe9/1/

Comment: BTW, probably the reason that you were using the wrong version is that the main demo page is on the 2.0 beta [which is not a "stable" release](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1060). But you should use the beta anyway, because a stable 2.0 will be released soon!